# Google Minify + Pass Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify

I'm using Google Minify to compress js files successfully.

I need to be able to pass a variable (like a `$_GET` variable) with this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/min/?g=site_searchresults_js"></script>
```

Is there a way to pass a variable with the above code?

Comment: What do you need to pass a variable to a JS file? Perhaps simply like this `includes/min/?g=site_searchresults_js&mynewvar=test`

Comment: If you have a script at `includes/min/`, then maybe.

Comment: For what purpose? So the script can use it, or so you can say which script to minify?

Comment: Purpose - so the script can use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of determining the query string parameters that were passed when the script was added into the document is described in [this article](http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html). It comes down to this kind of code:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var myScript = scripts[ scripts.length - 1 ];

var queryString = myScript.src.replace(/^[^\?]+\??/,'');

var params = parseQuery( queryString );

function parseQuery ( query ) {
   var Params = new Object ();
   if ( ! query ) return Params; // return empty object
   var Pairs = query.split(/[;&]/);
   for ( var i = 0; i < Pairs.length; i++ ) {
      var KeyVal = Pairs[i].split('=');
      if ( ! KeyVal || KeyVal.length != 2 ) continue;
      var key = unescape( KeyVal[0] );
      var val = unescape( KeyVal[1] );
      val = val.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
      Params[key] = val;
   }
   return Params;
}
```